# How to use PanoramaItem for navigation

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I'm trying to use PanoramaItem Header for navigation in my App. I named other pages with header names and override HeaderTemplate for Panorama control in my start page.

```
<controls:Panorama Title="PanoramaApp" 
                   HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaHeaderItemTemplate}">

            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Item1">
                          ...
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PanoramaHeaderItemTemplate">
      <Button Style="{StaticResource PanoramaHeaderItemStyle}"
              Click="PanoramaHeaderItem_Click"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

My problem is: How to get panorama HeaderItem value in code behind? In this case it would be *Item1*.

This is my code so far:

```
private void PanoramaHeaderItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            var HeaderName = ???
        }
```

I don't know hot to get that header name and use it to navigate to other page.

Comment: A: Get the DataContext from the button and get the "text" from that object. OR just access the Content property. Q: What are you trying to do when the user clicks the header?

Comment: Ok, thanks. It worket with DataContext. Put that in answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Well, you can get it from by answer above, but please don't. The Panorama is designed to see content on that page, not to navigate to other pages. If you want to navigate to pages, provide a list of pages to navigate to or tiles on the "MainPage" or something similar. Having Pano be your page navigation wastes space.

Comment: I'm trying to create Pano where PanoItem will have description of subsection and item header will be link to it. I already have Main Page with tile menu, I'm trying to create some sort of encyclopedia where this Pano is subcategory and that PanoItems are sub-subcategory. I will appreciate any design suggestions. I'm new with WP programming and I don't know best ways for application flow.

Comment: I am not quite picturing what you are trying to do, but it doesn't sound like the proper approach. Feel free to [contact me](http://www.visuallylocated.com/contact.aspx). No promises I'll be able to help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options to get the content from the button

1. Get the DataContext of the button

   MyObject myObj = button.DataContext as MyObject;
2. Get Content property of the button

   object content = button.Content;